Terminology for subgroup-like structure (under unary operation)
I have a set $V$ and a function $f: V \rightarrow V$. There also exists $W \subsetneq V$ such that $\forall w \in W, f(w) \in W$. I was wondering if there is any terminology to describe this situation. The closest thing I could find to what I describe is the idea of a subgroup, but $f$ is of course not a binary operation. Is there a specific term for this relationship between $V$, $W$, and $f$?
Though not necessarily required for the terminology I am looking for, for the particular example I am looking at $f$ is a bijection on $W$ but not on $V$.
Apologies if some of the terms I use are incorrect/inaccurate — I am an early undergraduate who does not know too much about algebra yet.

"$W$ is closed under $f$" is what I'm used to seeing.

I would also mention "$f$-stable". In general "a set equipped with a function" is the same as "a set equipped with an action of the monoid $\Bbb N$", so you can borrow terminology from the theory of monoid/group actions like "orbit" etc.

@IzaakvanDongen I think this is what I was looking for, but I admit I am not very familiar with the idea of a monoid. Are you saying that $f: S \rightarrow S$ is essentially equivalent to $g: S \times S \rightarrow {0, 1}$?

A monoid action of $M$ on $S$ is a map $\ast: \Bbb N \times S \to S$ such that $m \ast (m' \ast x)) = (mm') \ast x$ and $e \ast x = x$ for every $m, m' \in M$ and $x \in S$. This is equivalent to specifying a homomorphism $M \to (S^S, \circ)$. When $M = (\Bbb N, +)$ such an action is determined by the image of $1$, as $\Bbb N$ is the free monoid on ${1}$. It's fine if you don't understand all of that - this is somewhat advanced. To answer your question, all you need to know is that "stable", "invariant", "closed" are all sensible. I just thought I'd provide a bit of colour!

At least in linear algebra, a subset $W$ of $V$ with that property is said to be $f$-invariant or invariant under $f$.
See this for example.
As an example, consider the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.
The subset $\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb R$ is invariant under this function.
Also, note that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is not a bijection, but $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor \colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ it is.

Thank you for this response! The $V$ and $W$ in my particular example were in fact a vector space and a subspace, so this works well.
